# Google tag manager, no element id

Tags: google-analytics

There is **Google tag manager** (GTM) on the site I am working on but when we inspect the navigation with the GTM there is no element id. At this point i don't know where to begin. Do i rework the GTM in the module or the navigation in the code base?

[image: There is no element ID]